# About divergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log n)^p}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I have a question like this-

> Show that $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log n)^p}$$ diverges if $p>0$.

I have tried root test,ratio test etc with no help. We know that $n>\log n$ which gives $\frac{1}{(\log n)^p}>\frac{1}{ n^p}$ which does not help us because of the direction of inequality. I don't know how to proceed here and any help or hint would be very much appreciated!

Comment: For any $n$ large enough, $(\log n)^p\leq n$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio how to prove it? I tried plotting $(\log x)^{22}$ vs $x$ and got something which does not seem to satisfy what you mentioned above

Comment: @Prof.Shanku $(\log x)^p / x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Indeed, using the change of variables $y = \log x$ we have $y^p / e^y$ which indeed tends to $0$ as $y \to \infty$.

Comment: @user1892304 thanks for sharing this little trick. I was so dumb for not finding this. :p

Comment: @Prof.Shanku With pleasure :)

Comment: You have that :$n^{1/p}\geq \log(n^{1/p})=\frac 1p\log n.$ so $(\log n)^p\leq p^pn,$ which is enough to prove divergence.